Finite dominant morphism is surjective
Let $\varphi:X \rightarrow Y$ be a finite and dominant morphism of affine varieties, i.e. $\overline{\varphi(X)} = Y$ and the corresponding algebra homomorphism $\varphi^*:A(Y) \rightarrow A(X)$ is integral, then we have to prove that $\varphi$ is surjective.
I tried to prove this, but I fear it is wrong.
Let $y=(y_1,...,y_n) \in Y$ , then we can take the maximal ideal $m = (x_1-y_1,...,x_n-y_n)\subset A(Y)$. By lying over, there's a maximal ideal $q\subset A(X)$ such that $(\varphi^*)^{-1}(q) = m$
I also know that $\varphi^{-1}(y)=\varphi^{-1}(V(m)) = V((\varphi^*(m)))$ and since $(\varphi^*(m))\subseteq q$, we have $V(q)\subseteq V((\varphi^*(m)))$ which means that $\varphi^{-1}(y)$ is non empty, hence $\varphi$ is surjective.
However, I did not use the fact that $\varphi$ is a dominant morphism, or equivalently, that $\varphi^*$ is injective, which makes me think there's something wrong with this.

Set for simplicity $A = A(Y), B = A(X)$. I will assume that varieties are irreducible, so that $A$ and $B$ are integral domains.
You are right that this basically follows from going-up. However, going-up needs some "place to start at". So say $\mathfrak m \subset A$ is a maximal ideal. Then clearly, $0 \subset \mathfrak m$ is a chain of prime ideals in $A$, and since $A \to B$ is injective, $0 \subset B$ lies over $0 \subset A$. By going-up, you can extend the "chain" $0 \subset B$ to a chain of prime ideals $0 \subsetneq \mathfrak p \subset B$, such that $\mathfrak p$ lies over $\mathfrak m$. $\square$
An example where this fails if you think of a closed embedding, for example the line $\{x = 0\} \subset \mathbb C^2$. On coordinate rings, this is given by the surjection
$$\varphi: \mathbb C[x,y] \to \mathbb C[y], \quad x \mapsto 0.$$
And clearly, there is no prime ideal $\mathfrak p \subset \mathbb C[y]$ with $\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak p) = \mathfrak m := (x-1,y)$.
